# silverstripe 3 - How to add access control to generated data objects?

Tags: dynamic, silverstripe, access-control, data-objects

Good afternoon,

Please let me know if this question is not clear enough, I'll try my best to make as straight-forward as possible.
How can I add access control to objects that are generated by an end-user using my data object?

Example: I have a class that extends a DataObject. Someone logs in the back-end; fills out the form that's generated by the CMS for the data object. A record is then created in the database by the CMS.
I would like to add an access control to that newly created record in the database.

For a code scenario you can take a look at one of my posts: [Silverstripe 3 - Unable to implement controller access security from CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807801/silverstripe-3-unable-to-implement-controller-access-security-from-cms)

The only other way I can think of asking this question is: How to Dynamically (or programmatically) create permissions for records that are created by a DataObject extension via the CMS?

Thanks for your assistance.

**Update - Sample Code**

```
///>snippet, note it also has a Manager class that extends ModelAdmin which manages this!
class component extends DataObject implements PermissionProvider{
    public static $db = array(
         'Title' => 'Varchar',
         'Description' => 'Text',
         'Status' => "Enum('Hidden, Published', 'Hidden')",
         'Weight' => 'Int'
    );
    
    ///All the regular permission checks (overrides), for the interface goes here, etc...
    ///That is: canView, canDelete, canEdit, canCreate, providePermissions
}
```

Now, from the back-end an end-user can add components using the Manager Interface that's generated by extending ModelAdmin. How can I add individual permissions to those added components by the end-user?
Thanks.

**Update 2**
Example: Add Process Data Object that extends ModelAdmin will give you this in the back end
[image: Process DataObject with ModelAdmin features]

Then, when you click on the generated 'Add Process' button, you'll get this:
[image: Add Process form generated by ModelAdmin & DataObject]

Finally, someone fills out the form and clicks on the 'Create' button, which saves the data in the database. That looks like this:
[image: Added process MySQL data]

Now, on that record thats created in MySQL I'd like to add granular permissions to that record. Meaning, for every record created I want to be able to Deny/Allow access to it via a Group/Individual, etc.
Is that even possible with the SilverStripe framework? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the functions canView, canEdit, canDelete, and/or canCreate on your DataObject.

Each function will return true or false depending on the conditions you set - any conditions, not just what is defined in the CMS.

[See the example code on the tutorial site](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/modeladmin#permissions).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I may be missing something. I have implemented the canView, etc functions. But they're only allowing you to grant/deny access to the Object itself and not it's created content. For instance if I create something called 'Car', and it's object type is 'Component'; The permission methods only allow you to grant/deny access to object collection 'Component'. Thus every created component like 'Car' inherit those permissions, and I don't get the option to grant/deny access to the individually created components like 'Car'.

Comment: Any further ideas on this?

Comment: You need to implement the functions on each Dataobject that relates Car. So if Car has_many Component objects, the Component class would have to implement these methods, and check conditions set on Car. Your conditions on Condition would look like return $this->Car()->SomeProperty == 'foo'

Comment: Hi morning Elliot, I don't think I've explained myself properly or I'm misunderstanding something. Car doesn't have a defined class, in that it doesn't extend DataObject. It's created by an end-user in the CMS editor for Component Data Object. They can add 'Plane' as well is they wish, or anything for that matter. But for these created records I would like to dynamically add individual permissions to each created component. Can this be done? I've updated the above question to include a code sample, that may help further.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is possible in Silverstripe or has any ideas on this? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, it's been a while since I've asked. Can I get any assistance on this, or should I just give up on this thread and consider it dead?

Comment: Sorry, I have been busy with other work and don't usually have time to answer these. 

I don't understand how your users are creating a record in the CMS if they are not DataObjects. Please clarify your question, in particular with code describing these non-DataObjects.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the question above [Update 2]. I've added screenshots to assist in comprehending the question. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I'd start by implementing canView, canEdit, etc on Process. ie:

`public function canView() { return Permission::check('...');}`

Comment: I did all that (see original sample code), but it only deals with the object as a whole. Maybe I'm missing something, but the way that I found the canView, etc to work is that either you canView, canEdit, etc All or None of the objects data it doesn't give you the ability control each record individually.